# Why does a function declaration within a method's parenthesis result in method.variableName()?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, prototype

When I declare a variable within a javascript method's parenthesis, I am provided with an interesting addition to the function object. However, I cannot actually locate the resulting logic within the function object.

`[].forEach(towel = function(){console.log(42)})`

`console.log(towel) //function forEach.towel()`

Could someone please explain the logic behind this unique declaration?

NOTE: This evaluation was all done in the Chrome Dev Console. Perhaps that contributes to the specific syntax returned?

Comment: An assignment is an expression, it evaluates to something. The example is confusing, unless `towel` has been declared with `var` beforehand, it creates an implicit global variable. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @elclanrs why `console.log(towel) //function forEach.towel()` just curious

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Becuse you are assigning towel to the function

Comment: The `forEach.` part is interesting, I'm getting only `function ()` in FF.

Comment: FF always seems to do what I expect, I don't know why I keep using Chrome.

Comment: Not sure what `forEach.towel()` means...

Comment: @Teemu exactly. This is what I am confused with @ elclanrs

Comment: This evaluation was all done in the Chrome Dev Console. Perhaps that contributes to the specific syntax returned?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are making an assignment to a variable that has not been declared as var, it leaks to global scope.

The towel is now a variable in global scope.

Comment: But the output in the OP's log says, that it's a method of `forEach`, not a global variable ??? A weird output is the subject of the question.

Comment: That should be wrong. If you use ecma strict "use strict"; the first stmt would be an error that towel is not defined. Im pretty sure he would not have seen forEach.towel()

Comment: Yes, that should be wrong. The example doesn't tell us, if `towel` was declared. Anyway, `towel` should be either a variable in the global scope, or in the current scope, but never a method of `forEach`. Also there seems to be parentheses too, which makes the logging even more weird. I'd say this is just a bug in Chromes's console, (or OP has messed up with their loggings?)